# How does React deal with updating conditional children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I just found out that React does *not* instantiate all children of a component from scratch when it's updated. But how? I figured out that it solves that for arrays using the `key` prop, but how does this JSX code work?

```
<>
  <span>a</span>
  {someCondition && <span>b</span>}
  <span>c</span>
</>
```

When the condition inverts, there will be no way for React to distinguish the second and the third `span` without a `key` prop, but it somehow manages to.

My theory is that the JSX processor automatically puts `key` props on those 3 elements, but there may be other reasons.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: Thank you! Make a full answer out of that link so that I can mark it as the answer, please